# Push not updating array in DOM Vue

Tags: vue.js, dom, axios

I am using Vue and am trying to make live search. But on updating the content of search, it doesn't get updated.

Data do get update in array, when checked in dev tools. But DOM don't get updated.

**template**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <input type="text" v-model="input" placeholder="Search" @keyup="searching" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li v-for="(data,index) in availSearchData" :key="index">
        <a href="#">{{data.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**method**

```
searching() {
  if (this.input) {
    let url = this.domain + "search";
    axios
      .get(url, {
        params: {
          table: this.table,
          data: this.input
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.availSearchData = [];
        res.data.forEach(doc => {
          this.availSearchData.push(doc);
        });
      });
  }
}
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong. 
Please help out if possible.

Comment: can you show me your response?

Comment: In UI, I don't get anything.. In dev tools, after update wihen i give input 'salt':       
availSearchData:Array[1]
    0:Object
       coid:4
       name:"SALTS AND SUGAR"
       subcatid:"1"

Comment: just console.log(res) and show the output here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a computed property in your component and use that for parsing the template like this

```
<li v-for="(data,index) in availSearch" :key="index">
  <a href="#">{{data.name}}</a>
</li>
```

and computed property will be then

```
availSearch() {
  return this.availSearchData;
},
```

so this computed property always return the array if it is updated.

Also if your response is the array that you want to use exactly, try this

```
searching() {
  if (this.input) {
    let url = this.domain + "search";
    axios
    .get(url, {
      params: {
        table: this.table,
        data: this.input
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      this.availSearchData = [];
      Vue.set(this, 'availSearchData', res.data);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked amazingly, but i get this error  Computed property "availSearch" was assigned to but it has no setter.

Comment: Do not set the values using "availSearch". This is just for reading the values.

Comment: I did not set using "availSearch"

Comment: Then probably please provide your code so that I can check how exactly you are using this

Comment: and when there's only one element in array. It shows nothing in UI

Comment: Could you please provide the details with a fiddle, like this I cannot tell what could be the possible issue?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qgma9xny/         here's the fiddle, sorry Idk how to make fiddle

Comment: Also please provide some test data so that I can search for params: {
          table: 'test',
          data: 'test'
        }

Comment: Please help, where to add test data

Answer (score 4):

To add an item to the back of an array and get it to be reactive in Vue, below is what worked for me:

```
this.$set(this.items, 
          this.items.length, 
          JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.item))
         );
```

The `this.$set` is Vue's inbuilt array manipulation function that guarantees reactivity.
The `this.items` is the array, `this.items.length` (NOTE: it is `items.length` NOT `items.length - 1`) is to push a new index to the back of the array and finally, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.item))` is to clone the `this.item` into a new object before pushing into the array. The cloning part may not be applicable to you and I used `this` in variables because all the variables are declared in my `data()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your function from `mounted` hook. I think the problem is that you are trying to show data when the DOM is not rendered yet. By calling your function in `mounted` you get data back after DOM has been rendered.

```
mounted() {
    this.searching();
}
```

from [Vue website](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) "mounted: Called after the instance has been mounted, where el is replaced by the newly created vm.$el. If the root instance is mounted to an in-document element, vm.$el will also be in-document when mounted is called."

Comment: This worked, It did showed data.. but when there's only one element in array. It shows nothing

Comment: change the `:key="name"`. If `mounted` worked then the problem might be using the index as key

Comment: I can't actually, it contains duplicate data

Answer (score 0):

Possible explanations for this might be:

- You don't declare the property in the component and thus normal
  reactivity doesn't work.
- You are using index as the key in your array. This might confuse the
  reactivity system, so it does not necessarily know if the item
  changed. Try using the name of the item as the key instead.